# How to manually register context menus using command line

Tags: tortoisegit

Is there some way how I could manually register all default context menus within command line?

Something like: `TortoseGitProc.exe /command:register-default-context`

Comment: Why do you need something like this?

Comment: I don't want to install msi package. I want just extract msi package and notify user about manually registering context menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cli switch for registering the context menu as this is the task of the installer (as there is no portable version of TortoiseGit (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/726)).

Please note, that w/o the installer you won't have any icon overlays.

You can, however, if you really want to, look into the source of the installer to build your own `.reg` file (cf. https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/2258883b76f516432dc110f8659f92d0d68c1796/src/TortoiseGitSetup/StructureFragment.wxi#L43).

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer if it helped you. That’s the way to say thank you on stackoverflow.